# R - Apply a Custom Function by Group with Weightings

Tags: r, finance, portfolio

I have some data on stock returns. It includes portfolios for two investors over the same time months. Both investors own the same stocks, but in different amounts/weightings in their respective portfolios. The portfolio weights don't change during the months in question.

```
returns_df <- data.frame(
Investor = c("Jane","Jane","Jane","Jane","Jane","Tom","Tom","Tom","Tom","Tom"),
Month = c("January","February","March","April","May","January","February","March","April","May"),
Stock_A = c(0.2,0.3,-0.1,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.3,-0.1,0.2,0.4),
Stock_B = c(0.1,-0.3,0.5,0.6,-0.1,0.1,-0.3,0.5,0.6,-0.1),
Stock_C = c(0.5,0.7,-0.3,-0.3,0.1,0.5,0.7,-0.3,-0.3,0.1),
Weight_Stock_A = c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2),
Weight_Stock_B = c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4),
Weight_Stock_C = c(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4))
```

I have a custom R function that computes the variance on a portfolio of stocks -

```
lvar <- function(x, weights, na.rm = TRUE) {
      if (missing(weights)) {
        weights <- rep(1, ncol(x))
    }
  
    covmat <- var(x = x, na.rm = na.rm)
    utc <- upper.tri(covmat)
    wt.var <- sum(diag(covmat) * weights^2)
    wt.cov <- sum(weights[row(covmat)[utc]] *
                  weights[col(covmat)[utc]] *
                  covmat[utc])
    variance <- wt.var + 2 * wt.cov
    return(variance)
      }
```

I'd like to apply this function for each investor using their respective portfolio weights.

I've used sapply but it doesn't seem to apply the weights.

```
variance <- sapply(split(returns_df[3:5], returns_df$Investor), lvar,    
    weights=returns_df[6:8])
```

Suggestions appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the weights were not split up in the code.  We can use `Map` to loop over the list elements

```
Map(lvar, split(returns_df[3:5], returns_df$Investor),
    weights = split(returns_df[6:8], returns_df$Investor))
```

-output

```
$Jane
[1] 0.06327

$Tom
[1] 0.07496
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)#version >= 1.1.0
returns_df %>% 
  reframe(out = lvar(pick(starts_with("Stock")), 
  weights = pick(starts_with("Weight"))), .by = Investor)
```

-output

```
Investor     out
1     Jane 0.06327
2      Tom 0.07496
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `by`.

```
by(returns_df, returns_df$Investor, \(x) lvar(x[3:5], x[6:8])) |> c()
#    Jane     Tom 
# 0.06327 0.07496
```